# How to convert 'GameObject to Custom Class'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am basicly trying to convert an offline game into an online game, game uses VArmory for gun systems and Photon Network for online solution. So basicly I had a normal unity instantiate function which seems to work but when I try photon network's instantiate function it doesn't. How can I fix this?

Searched for similar problem but can't seem to find any.

```
Bullet bullet = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(bulletClone.name, transform.position, transform.rotation); // This is the code I am trying to use.
```

Says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'VArmory.Bullet'".

```
Bullet bullet = Instantiate(bulletClone, transform.position, transform.rotation); // Default code that was working.
```

So basicly I am trying to spawn bullets on network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well Unity's [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) returns `T` the type of the provided prefab.

`PhotonNetwork.Instantiate` returns a `GameObject` so you have to "manually" get the according component using [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) as usual

```
Bullet bullet = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(bulletClone.name, transform.position, transform.rotation).GetComponent<Bullet>();
```